# Payara 5.2022.2 Can not deploy modules to context-root /

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, payara

Environment details:

```
Payara 5.2022.2
Windows Server 2019 Enterprise LTSC
Apache Netbeans 14
JDK 17
```

This is the only machine and environment that produces this error when I try to deploy the same program to it:

```
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)
```

```
SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app
SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.Exception: Virtual server __asadmin already has a web module __admingui loaded at / therefore web module OIUSA_1 cannot be loaded at this context path on this virtual server
```

From other questions I have gathered that something is wrong with the `server-config->Virtual Servers` config of Payara, so here are two photos showing the only discernable difference between a working install of Payara, and the Windows Server that gives an error:

Working server:
[image: Working server enviornemnt]
[image: Working server enviornemnt2]

Not working server:
[image: Broken server enviornemnt]
[image: Broken server enviornemnt2]

So, the virtual server named `server` in the WORKING installation of Payara has a context path of `/` but the non working version doesn't. I'm not sure how to fix this, since I have tried fully uninstalling, rebooting, and re-installing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution:

In the `glassfish-web.xml` of the application configuration set the `Context Root = /your_project_name`

Then, deploy the application like expected and it should come up. Then enter the admin domain console and navigate to configurations->server-config->virtual servers-> then select the virtual server your application is running on and set the `Default Web Module` to your application. This will give the same result of running the application in the root folder (`/`). No deleting stuff from configuration files needed.